# Is this approach standard to use varags.length instead of booleans?

Tags: java

I've called this method multiple times in many places:

```
private String changeFirstCharCase(String word) {
    return Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
}
```

now I want to add `toUpperCase` ability to this method without creating another method and I need the caller to determine which one to go with using a boolean as an arguement.

```
private static String changeFirstCharCase(String word, boolean toUpperCase) {
    return toUpperCase
            ? Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1)
            : Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
}
```

in this case I've to add a true/false parameter to every call I've made.
but when I use varags, the calls that only need the `toUpperCase` ability need to add their note, which could be anything.

```
private static String changeFirstCharCase(String word, String... toUpperCase) {
    return toUpperCase.length > 0
            ? Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1)
            : Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
}
```

in this way the old methods calls are untouched.

```
changeFirstCharCase(facadeType);
```

and the new ones can call:

```
changeFirstCharCase(facadeType, "toUpperCase")
```

is this aprouch standard in case of readability and maintenance?

Comment: Personally, no I wouldn’t consider it a good practice, instead, I’d write two methods, one with the Boolean flag, one without (which would call the first with a default value), but’s that’s me

Comment: Also, what if someone passed in false to your method? You’re not taking into account the actual value. Also, you should aim for self documenting code, the varargs make it confusing as to what should be passed into the method and how they would be treated

Comment: It is hard to understand what is happening if you just see the method signature. Why are there several string values and what is the meaning.

Comment: Another minor disadvantage is that an Array object is allocated for the parameters. This will slow down things unnecessarily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like poor API design to me. Requiring the users of your API to pass an additional `String` argument (that could contain anything) in order to get the upper-case functionality is counter-intuitive.

If you don't want to touch the original methods, introduce new overloaded methods with the `boolean` parameter:

```
private String changeFirstCharCase(String word) {
    return changeFirstCharCase(word,false);
}

private String changeFirstCharCase(String word,boolean toUpperCase) {
    return toUpperCase
        ? Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1)
        : Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
}
```

or introduce a new method for the upper-case functionality, without the `boolean` parameter:

```
private String changeFirstCharCase(String word) {
    return Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
}

private String changeFirstCharToUpperCase(String word) {
    return Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1);
}
```

Though in this case it would also make sense to rename the original method to `changeFirstCharToLowerCase`.

Answer (score 2):

#### not OOP

Declare two static oveloaded method. From client side it looks, like `boolean toUpperCase` is an optional parameter.

```
public final class StringUtils {

    public static String changeFirstCharCase(String word) {
        return changeFirstCharCase(word, false);
    }

    public static String changeFirstCharCase(String word, boolean toUpperCase) {
        char ch = word.charAt(0);

        // if no change required, return given word 
        if (toUpperCase ^ Character.isUpperCase(ch))
            return word;

        return (toUpperCase ? Character.toUpperCase(ch) : Character.toLowerCase(ch)) + word.substring(1);
    }

}
```

*Client code:*

```
String lowerCaseFirstChar = StringUtils.changeFirstCharCase("aaa");
String upperCaseFirstChar = StringUtils.changeFirstCharCase("aaa", true);
```

#### OOP

According to OOP, you could declare two different functions for each operations and retrieve required function to the client:

```
public final class StringUtils {

    public static final Function<String, String> UPPER_CASE = str -> Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) ? str : str.charAt(0) + str.substring(1);
    public static final Function<String, String> LOWER_CASE = str -> Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(0)) ? str : str.charAt(0) + str.substring(1);

}
```

*Client code:*

```
boolean upperCase = true;
String str = (upperCase ? StringUtils.UPPER_CASE : StringUtils.LOWER_CASE).apply("aaa");
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a varargs does not fit here.

What if the caller passes

```
changeFirstCharCase(facadeType, "dummy")
```

You would still end up using `Character.toUpperCase`.

Using a boolean *seems* better here when compared to the varargs. But in future, you might need to add more transforms (like remove first char).

So,  IMO the user can pass the desired operation as an *enum*.

```
String changeFirstCharCase(String word, CharacterOperation op)  {..}

/*
  Determines what operation is to be done on a character
*/
enum CharacterOperation {
    UPPERCASE, LOWERCASE, REMOVECHAR //...;
}
```

The drawback is when the operations grow the method grows (and becomes difficult to manage). We can overcome this by having the logic of each opearation in a private method.
A natural extension of this is to have one method for each operation(as mentioned by Eran@).